# removing a jquery function from a class

Tags: jquery

I have a function called colors attached to an div called .viewShow. What I want to do is remove the function from the element not remove the element. I can't seem to find anything on it. Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to remove the color function from .viewShow?

```
if ($.showRestart == 'no') {
    $('.viewShow').colors();
    $.showRestart = 'yes';
} else {
    $('.viewShow');  // I want to remove colors ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ;
    $.showRestart = 'no';
}
```

I need to add some information to make the picture clearer. I have five divs called .panels they are all children of .viewShow. What I have been practising is using the extend function in the color obj (I believe). I am getting .panels to change colors, from what I can understand I am merging the two objects below and it works. What I need to understand is once the function has complete it works if I click again I want the .colors() to be destroyed. The css color is only a test I am adding other functionality.

```
     $(function(b){
            b.fn.extend({
                colors:function(d){
                    d=b.extend({                          
                        panelClass:".panel"
                    },d);
                    return this.each(function(){
                        var a=d;
                        b(this);
                        $(a.panelClass).css("background-color","red");
                    })
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: how is the function attached to the element?

Comment: Unbind() may help you http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: This seems more like a custom jquery plugin function...?

Comment: Consult `colors` plugin documentation for how to do that. There is no and cannot be a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use unbind function in jquery to remove function on the basis of class. for example: $('.classname').unbind('functionName')

Comment: He's not binding a function, he's extending the jquery builtins

Comment: Ok colors in not a plugin it is .colors() it is a function called colors:function(d){}

Answer (score 1):

Try this !It's remove your background color in the div

```
$('.viewShow').css("background-color","")
```

Refer this [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)

Answer (score 1):

This might be more then you want, but if you really want to strip it down then rebuild it

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/RK7s9/)

```
$newthing = $('.viewShow').clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
$('.viewShow').after($newthing).remove();
```